# Unable to load base64 encoded font in @font-face

Tags: html, fonts, base64, font-face

I am trying to embed base64-encoded font in the @font-face rule in the style in document's head.

```
<style> 
@font-face {
    font-family: OmoType-BoldStdTwo;
    src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,<base64data>);
}
div {
    font-family: OmoType-BoldStdTwo;
    font-feature-settings: "ss03" 1, "ss04" 1;
}
</style>
```

For some reason, it's not using my font, but Times (I see that when I look at the computed styles in Web inspector). I am testing on Google Chrome.

Here's the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/gfwdzx5s/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an issue with the font itself. I loaded the content of the font as a text and then base64encoded it, and that doesn't work, but when I loaded it as an array buffer and then converted to base64, it worked.